# how to describe an 8-digit seven-segment display with Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm supposed to interface to an 8-digit seven-segment display
[image]
[image]

This is how the circuit looks like:
[image]

And here's my code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module TimeMUXDisplay(input clk,input [5:0] DIN, 
output reg [7:0] E,output reg [6:0] C,output DP);

//Counter
reg [19:0]Counter;
initial
Counter=0;
always@(posedge clk)
Counter <= Counter + 1;

//3-to-8 decoder 
always @ (Counter[19:17])
    begin
    case(Counter[19:17])
    0: E<=8'b11111110;
    1: E<=8'b11111101; 
    2: E<=8'b11111011; 
    3: E<=8'b11110111; 
    4: E<=8'b11101111; 
    5: E<=8'b11011111; 
    6: E<=8'b10111111; 
    7: E<=8'b01111111; 
    default:E<=8'b11111111; 
    endcase
    end

//8-to-1 MUX

reg [5:0]DOUT;

    always@(DIN,Counter[19:17])
    begin
    case(Counter[19:17])
    3'd0:DOUT<=DIN[5:0];
    3'd1:DOUT<=6'b000001;
    3'd2:DOUT<=6'b000001;
    3'd3:DOUT<=6'b000001;
    3'd4:DOUT<=6'b000001;
    3'd5:DOUT<=6'b000001;
    3'd6:DOUT<=6'b000001;
    3'd7:DOUT<=6'b000001;
    default:DOUT<=6'b000001; // indicates null
    endcase
    end 

// Binary-to-seven segment
wire Enb;
assign Enb=DOUT[5];
always @(*)
    begin
        if(Enb)
            case(DOUT[4:1])
                0:C<=7'b1111110;
                1:C<=7'b0110000;
                2:C<=7'b1101101;
                3:C<=7'b1111001;
                4:C<=7'b0110011;
                5:C<=7'b1011011;
                6:C<=7'b1011111;
                7:C<=7'b1110000;
                8:C<=7'b1111111;
                9:C<=7'b1111011;
                default: C<=7'b1111111;
            endcase
        else C<=7'b1111111;
    end
    assign DP=DOUT[0];

endmodule
```

But when I try to test it using the Nexys 4DDR it just doesn't work (synthesis, implementation run without issues, but the 7-segment displays don't work), I don't know why.

By the way, this is what I have in the file describing the ports, but I'm sure it's fine, the problem should be in the code above:

```
## Clock signal
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { clk }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_35 Sch=clk100mhz
create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports {clk}];

##Switches
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DIN[0] }]; #IO_L24N_T3_RS0_15 Sch=sw[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN L16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DIN[1] }]; #IO_L3N_T0_DQS_EMCCLK_14 Sch=sw[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN M13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DIN[2] }]; #IO_L6N_T0_D08_VREF_14 Sch=sw[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DIN[3] }]; #IO_L13N_T2_MRCC_14 Sch=sw[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DIN[4] }]; #IO_L12N_T1_MRCC_14 Sch=sw[4]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DIN[5] }]; #IO_L7N_T1_D10_14 Sch=sw[5]

##7 segment display
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { C[0] }]; #IO_L24N_T3_A00_D16_14 Sch=ca
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { C[1] }]; #IO_25_14 Sch=cb
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { C[2] }]; #IO_25_15 Sch=cc
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { C[3] }]; #IO_L17P_T2_A26_15 Sch=cd
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { C[4] }]; #IO_L13P_T2_MRCC_14 Sch=ce
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { C[5] }]; #IO_L19P_T3_A10_D26_14 Sch=cf
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN L18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { C[6] }]; #IO_L4P_T0_D04_14 Sch=cg

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DP }]; #IO_L19N_T3_A21_VREF_15 Sch=dp

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[0] }]; #IO_L23P_T3_FOE_B_15 Sch=an[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[1] }]; #IO_L23N_T3_FWE_B_15 Sch=an[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T9    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[2] }]; #IO_L24P_T3_A01_D17_14 Sch=an[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[3] }]; #IO_L19P_T3_A22_15 Sch=an[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[4] }]; #IO_L8N_T1_D12_14 Sch=an[4]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[5] }]; #IO_L14P_T2_SRCC_14 Sch=an[5]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[6] }]; #IO_L23P_T3_35 Sch=an[6]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { E[7] }]; #IO_L23N_T3_A02_D18_14 Sch=an[7]
```

Edit:
Here's my test bench (I don't know if it's right):

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module sim_TimeMUXDisplay();
reg [5:0]DIN;
reg clk;
wire [7:0]E;
wire [6:0]C;
wire DP;
localparam [7:0]period=1;
TimeMUXDisplay uut(clk,DIN,E,C,DP);
initial
    begin
        clk=0;
        forever#(period/2.0)clk=~clk;
    end
initial
    begin
    DIN=0;
    #period DIN=10;
    #period DIN=20;
    #period DIN=121;
    end
endmodule
```

And this is the graph it creates:
[image]

And this is the schematic that Vivado creates with the code:
[image]

Comment: You say "The LEDs don't work". What do you mean? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Sorry, I meant the 7-segment displays, not the LED's. And they are supposed to show the numbers that the user selects with DIN (the switches). Right now, the 7-segment displays just show random lines.

Comment: Your code is quite complex. There is a lot of stuff here which might not be relevant and might be obscuring the problem. There is a lot of merit in posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way, you save those helping you time, you are more likely to get answers and you might even find the problem yourself in creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the circuit diagram, I wonder whether you are supposed to drive a zero to turn on a bar in the 7-segment display. So, I wonder whether this:

```
            0:C<=7'b1111110;
            1:C<=7'b0110000;
            2:C<=7'b1101101;
            3:C<=7'b1111001;
            4:C<=7'b0110011;
            5:C<=7'b1011011;
            6:C<=7'b1011111;
            7:C<=7'b1110000;
            8:C<=7'b1111111;
            9:C<=7'b1111011;
            default: C<=7'b1111111;
```

should be this:

```
            0:C<=7'b0000001;
            1:C<=7'b1001111;
            2:C<=7'b0010010;
            3:C<=7'b0000110;
            4:C<=7'b1001100;
            5:C<=7'b0100100;
            6:C<=7'b0100000;
            7:C<=7'b0001111;
            8:C<=7'b0000000;
            9:C<=7'b0000100;
            default: C<=7'b0000000;
```